# AdminLTE, data-confirm does not work

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, adminlte

i'm bulding a rails application, using AdminLTE as HTML,CSS template, i find out that:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/prodo/10">Destroy</a>
```

does not work, it simply redirect me to /prodo/10 the attribute of data-confirm and data-method are not working, i think it cuold be something with javascript....
 can anyone help me ?

Comment: Of course it redirect you to that because of the `href="/prodo/10"`. What would you expect?! If you mean that by adding `data-confirm` to your anchor, it should open a confirm box or something like that, the check your console for errors.

Comment: yes, but with data-confim attribute it could show me an alerts, and with data-method the request could be in DELETE method not in GET or POST

Comment: no errors in console....